# Inline form factory does not load all documents after POST in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I need some help with inline formset in Django.  I am using the inline form set factory to upload documents to Document model which has foreign key reference to Department Table as follow:

**model.py:**

```
class Department(models.Model):
    DepId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ShortName = models.CharField (max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.DepId) + " "+  self.ShortName+ " is created!")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Department' # Table Name
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'Departments' # Verbose Name of Table.

class Document(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (('Type1', 'Report Type 1'),
                ('Type2', 'Report Type 2'),)
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    DocType = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=CATEGORY)
    DocContent = models.FileField(upload_to='reports/')
    DepId = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="DepId")     
    UploadedDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.Name))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Document'
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'Document'

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.DocContent.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

**view.py**

```
def doc_loading_view(request, pk,  *args, **kwargs):
    DocumentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Location, 
                                            Document,
                         fields=('Name', 'DocContent', 'DocType',), 
                                               extra=1)
    department = Department.objects.get(DepId=pk)
    formset = DocumentFormSet(queryset=Document.objects.none(), instance=department)
    context = {
        'department': department,
        'form': formset,
        }
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = PaymentDocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=location)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                fileform = form.save(commit=False)
                print (fileform.Name)

            return redirect('getdoc', pk=department.DepId)
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Errors in Formset: "+formset.errors)

    return render(request, "getdoc", context)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Department Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                    
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ request.session.dep_name }}</td>
                    </tr> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th><h5>Upload the Document</h5><h6>You must have atleast one Report 1 and one Report 2 types</h6></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                    
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            <td id="messages">{{message}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <form action = "" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
                        <table class="table table-sm">
                        {{ form.management_form }}
                        {% for f in form %}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        {%for field in f.visible_fields %}
                                            <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            {% endif %}
                            <tr class="formset_row">
                                {% for field in f.visible_fields %}
                                    <td>
                                        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                        {% if forloop.first %}
                                            {% for hidden in f.hidden_fields %}
                                                {{ hidden }}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                        {{ field }}
                                    </td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                        <button type="submit" name ="fl_upload" class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm"><span class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up fa-2x">Upload File</span></button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    </tr> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'Add More Doc',
        deleteText: 'Remove',
        prefix: 'paydocumentform_set'
    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

I am using the Javascript from this [git repository](https://github.com/adandan01/mybook/tree/master/static/formset).

So when I load the multiple documents, form set always return only one document.  Is there any issue with my code? 
I am not sure this behaviour due to extra=1, which I specified in formset definition.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your view.py. When the formset is defined, you're using a custom queryset, queryset=Document.objects.none().

```
formset = DocumentFormSet(queryset=Document.objects.none(), instance=department)
```

This queryset returns no records so the only row returned in the extra (blank) row. Removing querysetqueryset=Document.objects.none() should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Scott for your prompt response.  I placed the queryset because I don't want user to see any uploaded document.  Therefore, when I set objects.none() it will not show any existing documents to user.  Any other suggestion.

Comment: Does the error occur when you are rendering the form or when you are saving the form?

Comment: Actually I don't get error but I only get the last file which I upload. So, for example I upload two files.  File 1 and File 2 (assuming File 2 is last entry before I submit the form) then on POST request I only get File 2 whereas I am expecting File 1 as well.

Comment: My use case is I want department manager to upload the weekly report for  employee hours and employee incident report.  But I don't want department manager to show any previous document which are uploaded therefore I use query set as objects.None() so it does not return anything.  So I just want manager to upload report without seeing in prior reports and they can upload multiple reports.  Thank you.

Comment: I've read through your code several times and cannot find any obvious errors. However, one issue I've noted from experience using inline formsets and dynamic formsets is that it's important to use the same prefix and explicitly define the prefix when you create the formset. I hate to offer "try this, try that" advise but... Try adding prefix=paydocumentform_set when you instantiate formset.

Comment: Thank you Scott for your tips.  Indeed that's typo on my end. I update that but did not help.  If possible can you share some knowledge on how does "extra" field work on inline formset.  When I change extra = 3 then I was able to load up-to 3 docs but the fourth doc it ignored.  When I change extra = 2 then I am fine with only two.  So I  can I allow user to add more documents than what's defined in extra.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Extra defines the number of blank forms that will be added to the initial formset. It does not affect the ability to add or remove blank forms using dynamic formsets.

Comment: Thanks Scott really appreciate your help.  Let me continue with my debugging see if anything else can help.  Really appreciate your help and prompt response.